# Clojure java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn error

Tags: recursion, clojure

I trying to write simple factorial function in clojure, but i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I know this error is usually due to an extra parenthesis, but I am not sure about this case.

First I wrote function in LISP, and it works as it should.
Code:

```
(defun factorial (n)
    (if (= n 1) 
        1
        (* (factorial (1- n)) n )
    )
)
(factorial 5)
```

Then I tried it in clojure, where it doesn't work.
Clojure code:

```
(defn factorial [n]
    (if (= n 1) 
        1
        (* (factorial(n)) n)
    )
)

(defn -main
    [& args]
    (println(factorial 5))
)
```

Comment: Reopened this question: the duplicate question was about a completely different problem in a different incorrectly-implemented fibonacci function.

Answer (score 4):

You've got an extra set of parens in your recursive call to factorial, probably because you meant to decrement n, it should be

```
(defn factorial [n]
    (if (= n 1) 
        1
        (* (factorial (dec n)) n) ;; <== 
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

As MarkNFI showed decrementing has its own operator `inc`.

But to show you the problem in your code:

```
(defun factorial (n)
    (if (= n 1) 
        1
        (* (factorial (1- n)) n ) ;; (1- n) must be changed to (dec n) or (- n 1)
    )
)
(factorial 5)
```

`(1- n)` is not the way operators in clojure work. You have to place the operator first. So in your case it would be: `(- n 1)`

Comment: It's Common Lisp snippet, `1-`  in CL is what `dec` in Clojure is.